# Combine curved paths with fingerings

Tags: lilypond, fingering

I want to mark notes with fingerings where the finger number has a bow below or above.

First, I am creating the bows:

```
upper-bow = 
#'(
  (M 0 0)
  (C 0.6 0.2 1.4 0.2 2 0)
)

lower-bow =
#'(
  (M 2 0)
  (C 1.4 -0.2 0.6 -0.2 0 0)
)

bam-fingering = \markup {
  \path #.2 \upper-bow
}

sefid-fingering = \markup {
  \path #.2 \lower-bow
}
```

And then I use it in a fingering using `\finger`:

```
\sectionLabel "test"
\time 2/4
\relative c'' {
    d4\finger \markup{2 \bam-fingering}
    d4\finger \markup{2 \sefid-fingering}
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

I need the bows to be exactly above or below the number, not besides it. I tried different things like `\combine` but that didn't help.

Comment: Out of interest: What are the curves supposed to mean?

Comment: It's from a common notation to mark fingerings/strings for playing [the Setar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setar): the first string has no mark; the second string - also called sefid for white - has a lower bow; and the bam string has an upper bow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to combine a list of markups into a single markup you’d want to use `\overlay` like this:

```
\relative c'' {
    d4\finger \markup\overlay{ 2 \bam-fingering }
    d4\finger \markup\overlay{ 2 \sefid-fingering }
}
```

Now, if you want this to align you might want to do something like

```
\relative c'' {
    d4\finger \markup\overlay{\center-align 2 \center-align \bam-fingering}
    d4\finger \markup\overlay{\center-align 2 \center-align \sefid-fingering}
}
```

Alternatively you might define your commands as markup functions that draw these paths around their argument, similar to say

```
\relative c'' {
    d4\finger \markup{\overtie 2}
    d4\finger \markup{\undertie 2}
}
```

---

Final solution:

```
#(define-markup-command (bam-tie layout props text) (markup?)
  "Draw a bam-tie over a fingering."
  (interpret-markup layout props
    #{\markup\overlay{\center-align #text \translate #'(.0 . 1.4) \center-align \bam-fingering}#}))

#(define-markup-command (sefid-tie layout props text) (markup?)
  "Draw a sefid-tie under a fingering."
  (interpret-markup layout props
    #{\markup\overlay{\center-align #text \translate #'(.0 . -.4) \center-align \sefid-fingering}#}))
```

Comment: I defined a markup command as you said, using `\overlay`. I also used `\translate` to do a final adjustment of the positioning :) Exactly what I needed, thanks!